# Процесс Python грузит ядро процессора на 100%

Tags: python, cmd, консоль, macos, вирусы

MacOS Catalina. Скачал пиратку одного приложения и появилась проблема. После запуска VS Code запускается процесс Python, грузящий процессор. Скорее всего, майнер. Пытался избавиться вручную, копаясь в Application Support, но без толку. Скачал антивирус - не помог. В чем может быть проблема? Прилагаю лог этого процесса:

````
/Users/axor/Desktop/\xd0\xba\xd1\x83\xd1\x80\xd1\x81\xd1\x8b/py
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/math.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/select.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/array.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/binascii.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_contextvars.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_asyncio.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_json.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_uuid.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_datetime.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_queue.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_random.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_sha512.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_multiprocessing.cpython-39-darwin.so
txt
/usr/lib/dyld
0
->(none)
1
->(none)
2
->(none)
3
/dev/urandom
4
count=0, state=0x8
5
->0xc46f96b960a768a5
6
->0xc46f96b960a7745d
8
->0xebfb234a0e66565d
9
->0xfaf5b9fd55bd6481
11
->0x2cec7372e0a0651```
````

Comment: пиратка на маке пхахах.. срубите процесс и заблочьте его в `firewall`

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, проблема была вовсе не в майнере и это была беда с плагином Python от Microsoft в VS Code. Почему? Понятия не имею. Скачал версию полугодичной давности и таким образом устранил проблему.